# How to ignore the following compiler warning?

Tags: c++, g++

When compiling the following piece of code (g++ 4.6), I get the (expected) warning message:
`./test.cpp:3:7: attention : address of local variable ‘ii’ returned [enabled by default]`.

```cpp
int *get_ii()  
{  
  int ii = 2;
  return &ii;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int *ii;
  ii = get_ii();
  return 0;
}
```

Question: is there a compiler option that would allow me to ignore this warning message at compile time?

**Reason**: this is purely for teaching purpose. I'd like to show this piece of code to the audience and ask what's wrong with it. That's why I want to hide the warning message, as it is a big clue.

Comment: Is there a good reason you'd want to?

Comment: Why would you want to ignore this!? Any attempt to dereference `ii` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @SebGR: the first reaction to a warning should not be *how do I ignore it ?*, it should be *what is the compiler trying to tell me ?*.

Comment: Why don't you use reference instead if you are really interested to use the integer value in main function?

Comment: @Subhajit NO! Just as bad and undefined!

Comment: When its just for teaching purposes, why don't you just wrap the gcc call and filter it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend against using this in most cases, but since this is for teaching purposes, you can use the `-w` flag to suppress all warnings from g++. You can also use `-Wno-return-local-addr` to suppress that specific warning if you upgrade to a more recent version of g++.

Comment: I don't think that this available in gcc 4.6 as PR 54930 is from oct 2012 (making it available in any version in svn only)

Comment: @PlasmaHH, as I said, `-Wno-return-local-addr` isn't available in 4.6, but `-w` is available in 4.6.

Comment: Looks like `-Wno-return-local-addr` is not working for me, but `-w` is. Thanks!

Comment: @DirkHolsopple: The point was that it isn't available in any released version of gcc.

Answer (score 10):

There's no way to do it in gcc (there's `pragma warning` in MSVS) and this is a warning **you shouldn't ignore**.

Returning the address of a variable local to a function is undefined behavior. When `get_ii` returns, the variable `ii` no longer exists, but you're returning a pointer to it. If you changed it to

```
int *get_ii()  
{  
  static int ii = 2;
  return &ii;
}
```

it would solve the problem and the warning.

Comment: Relevant paragraph from the standard? Surely it's possible dereferencing that's UB?

Comment: and possibly introduce another... "I had a problem and tried solving it with threads, now I have two problems"

Comment: @AndreasBrinck common knowledge (which this is) doesn't need support from the standard.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: not even a matter of threads, this is introducing global state!

Comment: @PlasmaHH Don't you mean " "I had a problem and tried solving it with threads, problems have now two I"

Comment: @AndreasBrinck doing anything with an invalid pointer is (including copying it, even if you don't use it)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: No mean II what wrote.

Comment: I believe you, but it would still be nice with a quote from the standard.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: I can't just quickly find it, but remember a discussion about this topic many years ago, mainly about why this should (or should not) be UB. Someone came up with a (unfortunately not hypothetical) architecture with tagged pointers, where even copying around pointers into unmapped memory would trap. I guess thats also somehow related to the term "odr-used" being introduced just recently.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: C99/ISO9899:1999(e) 6.2.6.1-5 might give a little more hint about those things.